# Laravel passed argument

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with my Laravel app. I'm trying to make scraper and It looks like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Scraper\Amazon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ScraperController extends Controller
{
    public $test;

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->test = new Amazon();
       
        return $this->test;
    }
```

As you can see I have created new folder inside app that is called Scraper, and I have Amazon.php file that looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Scraper;

use Goutte\Client;

class Amazon
{
    public string $test = ''; 

    public function __construct()
    {
        return "test";
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B002SZEOLG/');

        $crawler->filter('#productTitle')->each(function ($node) {
            $this->test = $node->text()."\n";
        });

        return $this->test;
    }
}
```

And this is always returning error like

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the
> type string or null, object given,

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line of code causes that error?

Comment: It says only  
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\eComet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php on line 65 in file C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\eComet\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php on line 412

Comment: Not very familiar with Laravel, but you're defining an `index` method in your `Amazon` class and aren't actually calling it. You might want to do `return $this->test->index()` instead then, in `ScraperController#index`. Having an `index` method in your custom (non-controller) class is a bit weird though.

Answer (score 14):

I believe the problem is returning the object itself `(return $this->test),` you should use `return response()->json([$this->test]);`

Answer (score 3):

return `var_dump($node->text());`  before `return $this->test` to be sure test() is returning the expected value.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a post request to a function

```
$contest =  Contest::with('contestRatings')->where('id', '=', $contest_id);
return $contest;
```

I needed `get()` to make it work

```
$contest =  Contest::with('contestRatings')->where('id', '=', $contest_id)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue resolved for me when I added `->get()`.

Try:

```
return $this->test->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax to return your response.

```
return response()->json($this->test);
```